# How to set port and connectionFactory during run time for Spring TCP integration

Tags: java, spring, tcp, spring-integration

Basically, I am not aware of port before hand. I will make a REST request to a host to send the port number. I am getting the port number, but not able to move ahead as I am not able to set connection factory into `inBoundClient` with received port number. Please have a look at the code below, to understand the problem.

I have tcp connections defined as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tcpclient" />
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-ip="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip/spring-integration-ip.xsd">
<context:annotation-config />
<!--Deserializer for incoming data on the socket -->
<bean
class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArraySingleTerminatorSerializer"
id="serializeAndDeserializer">
<constructor-arg type="byte" value="0" />
</bean>



<!-- TCP Client configuration -->

<!-- Channels for communication -->

<int:channel id="tcp-client-input" />

<int:channel id="message" />

<int:channel id="message-serviceActivator" />

<int:gateway id="gateway" service-interface="com.tcpclient.ClientGateway"
default-request-channel="tcp-client-input" default-reply-channel="message" />



<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter
id="outBoundClient" channel="tcp-client-input" 
retry-interval="60000" auto-startup="false" />

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter
id="inBoundClient" channel="message" 
client-mode="true" auto-startup="false" retry-interval="60000" />


<int:object-to-string-transformer
input-channel="message" output-channel="message-serviceActivator" />
<int:service-activator input-channel="message-serviceActivator"
method="onRtlsMessageArrival">
<bean class="com.tcpclient.HandleMessage" />
</int:service-activator>
</beans>
```

---

Config manager

In my class, I am trying below:

```
@component
public class ConfigManager {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("clientFactory")
TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean connFactory;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("inBoundClient")
SmartLifecycle inboundClient;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("outBoundClient")
SmartLifecycle outBoundClient;

public void initialize(Boolean canStart) {

try {
   if (canStart) {
                    String portResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(SYSTEM_OPEN_SOCK_URI, openSockeEntity,
                            String.class);
                    int portNumber = parsePortFromJson(portResponse);
                    connFactory.setPort(portNumber);
                    TcpReceivingChannelAdapter receiver = (TcpReceivingChannelAdapter) inboundClient;
                     receiver.setConnectionFactory(connFactory);
                     receiver.start();
                    EventDrivenConsumer sender = (EventDrivenConsumer) outBoundClient;
                    sender.start();
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Error occured while fetching data.");
}
}
}
```

But, at the line `receiver.setConnectionFactory(connFactory);`,
 I have compiler error,
 `The method setConnectionFactory(AbstractConnectionFactory) in the type TcpReceivingChannelAdapter is not applicable for the arguments (TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean)`.
Is there anyway I could set port dynamically.

EDIT: As per Gary's suggestion,

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("outboundClient.handler")
TcpSendingMessageHandler outBoundClient;`,

outBoundClient.setConnectionFactory(connFactory);
outBoundClient.setRetryInterval(60000);
outBoundClient.afterPropertiesSet();
outBoundClient.start();
```

But, I have this below error:

`Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.tcp-client-input'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers`

when I try `gateway.send("ACK");` one of my beans. but I have my `outBoundClient` having `channel="tcp-client-input"`

Comment: Of course you will get an exception... A `TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean` obviously isn't a `ConnectionFactory`. It is a `FactoryBean` which creates a `ConnectionFactory`.

Comment: @M.Deinum, yeah I agree with that. It was just one of the trials I did, Actually it is TcpNetClientConnectionFactory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the port is set in a constructor, you can't change it after the bean is created.

You also can't change the port on a connection factory bean after is has already created its connection factory.

You need to create the connection factory yourself (`new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(...)`) rather than have Spring create it - be sure to call `afterPropertiesSet()` after creating and configuring it and before you add it to the adapter.

Comment: Thanks. OKay will do that and I will set this new connection factory into inBoundClient. But, how about outBoundClient , It is of type EventDrivenConsumer, I cant set connectionFactory here. And more over, I tried with TcpSendingMessageHandler, but I cant typecast EventDrivenConsumer to TcpSendingMessageHandler.

Comment: Use `@Qualifier("outboundClient.handler")` to get a reference to the message handler.

Comment: I have used it, now I have a different problem, which is confusing to me. Though I have subscriber, it complains, no subscriber found. I have edited question with these details.

Comment: Your adapter (EventDrivenConsumer) will not subscribe to the channel until it is `start()`ed - change auto-startup to true, or inject the endpoint and start it after you inject the connection factory into the handler.