# int-ip:tcp-connection-event-inbound-channel-adapter not working when I have TcpConnectionExceptionEvent

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I went through below post:
[In spring integration, how do I catching different exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646963/in-spring-integration-how-do-i-catching-different-exceptions)

After this I have defined event handler for `org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpConnectionExceptionEvent`
as below:

```
<int:gateway id="gateway" service-interface="com.tcpclient.ClientGateway"
    default-request-channel="tcp-client-input"
    default-reply-channel="message"/>
<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter
    id="outBoundClient" channel="tcp-client-input"
    retry-interval="60000" auto-startup="true"/>

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter
    id="inBoundClient" channel="message" auto-startup="false"
    retry-interval="60000"/>
<int-ip:tcp-connection-event-inbound-channel-adapter
    channel="tcpReceiveError"
    event-types="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpConnectionExceptionEvent"/>
```

My service activator is:

```
@Component
public class ErrorHandler{

private static final Logger logger =   LoggerFactory.getLogger(ErrorHandler.class);

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "tcpReceiveError")
public void handleError(Message m) {

    logger.error("TcpError", m.getPayload());

}

}
```

At the first place if host is not up or port is not opened when I try to connect for first time,my `handleError(Message m)` is not executed as per below conversation.

[int-event:inbound-channel-adapter not working when there is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38566363/int-eventinbound-channel-adapter-not-working-when-there-is-java-net-connectexce)

But, once connected and I start receiving messages, if the server closes port or goes down in between, `handleError(Message m)` is not executed.

Please do let me know if I have some wrong configurations in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume this is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38563054/how-to-set-port-and-connectionfactory-during-run-time-for-spring-tcp-integration).

In that case, it's because your connection factory is not spring-managed - so it doesn't get an event publisher.

You should make the bean that creates the connection factory implement `ApplicationEventPublisherAware` and save off the publisher in a field. Then, when you create the connection factory, you need to set the property.

Without that, you should see warnings like this in the log...

```
this.logger.warn("No publisher available to publish " + event);
```

Comment: Yes, it is based on same question.Yes, I see that warning in the log.
I will try the solution and get back if I see any hiccups. Thanks once again :)

Comment: One question, `when you create the connection factory, you need to set the property` - Should I set publisher property? If yes, with what? I mean Should I call setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher)?

Comment: As I said in the answer - if the bean that creates the factory is `ApplicationEventPublisherAware` you will be given the publisher - in the setter, store it in a field (`this.applicationEventPublisher = applicationEventPublisher`); then, when you create the connection factory, pass it in there. Yes; `setApplicationEventPublisher(this.applicationEventPublisher)`.